# How will make a timer just like in the scoring that I have

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
var score = 0;
var mySkin: GUISkin;
var GUIScore: GUIText;

function Start() {
    GUIScore.text = "Score: 0";
}

function OnTriggerEnter(other: Collider) {
    if (other.tag == "MissionComplete") {
        SaveScore();
    }
    if (other.tag == "Coin") {
        Debug.Log("Other object is a coin");
        score += 50;
        GUIScore.text = "Score: " + score;
        Debug.Log("Score is now " + score);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    } else if (other.tag == "SpecialCoin") {
        Debug.Log("Other object is a coin");
        score += 150;
        GUIScore.text = "Score: " + score;
        Debug.Log("Score is now " + score);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    } else if (other.tag == "Rock") {
        Debug.Log("Other object is a rock");
        score += -20;
        GUIScore.text = "Score: " + score;
        Debug.Log("Score is now " + score);
        if (score <= 0) {
            Application.LoadLevel("NextLevel");
        }
    }
}

function SaveScore() {
    if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("JScore")) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("JScore", score);
    }
    Application.LoadLevel("LoadScene");
}
```

I want a timer that will record after finishing an objective
Just like a time recorder that will record the time in the highscore board.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more please. Saving [time](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) at start and building the delta seems not what you are looking for.

Comment: I have a game similar to a race game which will record the time after finishing the objectives and I want to save the score on a scene as a identification to highscore of it

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Save Game JSON+Binary asset store plugin
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3675
You can also just store data in an xml file or also using PlayerPrefs but ideally you want something a bit more structured.